# MariaDB Connector C, mysql_stmt_fetch_column() and memory corruption

Tags: c++, mysql, c, mysql-connector-c, mariadb-connector-c

I'm working on a wrapper for MariaDB Connector C. There is a typical situation when a developer doesn't know a length of a data stored in a field. As I figured out, one of the ways to obtain a real length of the field is to pass a buffer of lengths to **mysql_stmt_bind_result** and then to fetch each column by calling **mysql_stmt_fetch_column**. But I can't understand how the function **mysql_stmt_fetch_column** works because I'm getting a memory corruption and app abortion.

Here is how I'm trying to reach my goal

```
// preparations here
...
if (!mysql_stmt_execute(stmt))
{
    int columnNum = mysql_stmt_field_count(stmt);

    if (columnNum > 0)
    {
        MYSQL_RES*   metadata = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(stmt);
        MYSQL_FIELD* fields   = mysql_fetch_fields(metadata);
        MYSQL_BIND*  result   = new MYSQL_BIND[columnNum];

        std::memset(result,     0, sizeof (MYSQL_BIND) * columnNum);

        std::vector<unsigned long> lengths;

        lengths.resize(columnNum);

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNum; ++i)
            result[i].length = &lengths[i];

        if (!mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, result))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                  int status = mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt);

                  if (status == 1)
                  {
                      m_lastError = mysql_stmt_error(stmt);
                      isOK = false;
                      break;
                  }
                  else if (status == MYSQL_NO_DATA)
                  {
                      isOK = true;
                      break;
                  }

                  for (int i = 0; i < columnNum; ++i)
                  {
                      my_bool isNull = true;

                      if (lengths.at(i) > 0)
                      {
                          result[i].buffer_type   = fields[i].type;
                          result[i].is_null       = &isNull;
                          result[i].buffer        = malloc(lengths.at(i));
                          result[i].buffer_length = lengths.at(i);

                          mysql_stmt_fetch_column(stmt, result, i, 0);

                          if (!isNull)
                          {
                              // here I'm trying to read a result and I'm getting a valid result only from the first column
                          }
                      }
                  }
             }
        }
  }
```

If I put an array to the **mysql_stmt_fetch_column** then I'm fetching the only first field valid, all other fields are garbage. If I put a single MYSQL_BIND structure to this function, then I'm getting an abortion of the app on approximately 74th field (funny thing that it's always this field). If I use another array of MYSQL_BIND then the situation is the same as the first case.

Please help me to understand how to use it correctly! Thanks

[Minimal reproducible example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p0l7tIJIMrdyrNg5KmA46E-y9aSLhoMD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just because you have memory corruption here doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere that gets executed before this point, and this is only the place where the program finally crashed because of that. And this is exactly why stackoverflow.com's [help] instructs you to show a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce your problem. Having said that, the usage of `mysql_stmt_fetch_column` seems to be wrong, and that's the reason for the crash. But since it's only a guess, I can't say it's the answer, without a [mre].

Comment: Yes I know that the usage of mysql_stmt_fetch_column is wrong because it is exactly what I meant in my question :D The question is what exactly is wrong. To have a solid theory would be the best thing since documentation of MySQL/MariaDB connector says almost nothing about this function and the example presented in the documentation is quite obvious and useless in my case

Comment: All you know is that it crashes there. That, in of itself, proves absolutely nothing whatsoever, for the reasons that I already explained. The usage may be perfectly correct, but the crash happened due to memory corruption that happened somewhere else because some other function was used incorrectly. It didn't crash immediately, but corrupted memory, and you're crashing here. A [mre] is needed to fully analyze the reason for the crash.

Comment: Having said that, the seemingly wrong usage of `mysql_stmt_fetch_column`  here is that the shown code assumes that this function writes its result to `result[i]`. I find nothing in `mysql_stmt_fetch_column`'s documentation to support this hypothesis. All that it states is that it stores its output into `*result`. The End.

Comment: Okay... you find the example in the topic

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so?

Comment: So? `mysql_stmt_fetch_column` places the result in `*result`. The shown code expects `i`'th column to be stored in `result[i]`, instead. Hence the crash.

Comment: As I said in the topic, if I put a single MYSQL_BIND structure (a pointer, of course) it causes an abortion. If the function places the result in *result then it doesn't matter how many MYSQL_BIND are allocated there because in this case the only one element is enough. But it's not. If you can see, there is a `mysql_stmt_fetch_column(stmt, result, i, 0);` call, not a `mysql_stmt_fetch_column(stmt, &result[i], i, 0);` so I suppose your theory is not true